# Why is it that if $\emptyset \neq S \subset \mathbb{R}$ that is not sequentially compact, there exists an unbounded sequence in $S$?

Tags: real-analysis

I read this somewhere and it doesn't make sense to me. Doesn't $S$ not being sequentially compact mean that it is either not bounded or not closed? If so, why can't $S$ simply be not closed but bounded and thus not have an unbounded sequence?

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't make sense to me either. Where did you read it? There may be a hidden, standing assumption that $S$ is closed?

Comment: I read it in a textbook solution to a problem. After re-reading the problem a few times, I know for sure that there is no assumption that $S$ is closed. I guess the solution is incorrect.